# SSJS WSProxy: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

I am trying to get a list of MobileConnect Keywords and their associated IDs using WSProxy.

I have created a CloudPage Code Resource (JSON) and written the following script:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core", "1");
var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

try {

    var cols = [ "ID", "CustomerKey" ];

    var data = api.Retrieve("UnsubscribeFromSMSPublicationMOKeyword", cols);

    if (data != null) {
        Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(data));
    } else {
        Platform.Response.Write('{}');
    }


} catch(e) {

    Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(e));

}  

</script>
```

However, the response I get when I publish the page and refresh in the browser is:

```
{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}
```

Has anyone ever come across this error before?

Any idea how I change my script so that it works?

Comment: I think I figured this out... Needed to to make Retrieve() lowercase.

Comment: yes, WSProxy, which is SSJS, is case sensitive - so you need to use lowercase retrieve like so: `var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter);`